# Implications of convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Consider two sequences of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}_n$, $\{Z_n\}_n$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose that

(1) $Z_n\in o_p(1)$, i.e. $Z_n$ converges in probability to $0$

(2) $X_n+Z_n\geq 0$ $\forall n$

(3) $X_n\leq 0$ $\forall n$

I want to show that $X_n\in o_p(1)$

Any suggestion? I get the intuition but I don't know how to show it formally

Comment: Do (2) and (3) imply that $Z_n\geq0$ and more importantly $|X_n|\leq|Z_n|$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$? In that case you get $\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>\varepsilon]\leq\mathbb{P}[|Z_n|>\varepsilon]\rightarrow 0$ which is already the definition for convergence in probability.

Comment: Is it important to have strict inequalities?

Comment: I don't think so, in fact I misstyped and I'll correct it, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{|X_n|\gt \varepsilon\}&=\mathbb P\{X_n\lt -\varepsilon\} \quad\mbox{ by }(3)\\
&=\mathbb P\{X_n+Z_n\lt Z_n-\varepsilon\}\\
&\leqslant \mathbb P\{0\lt Z_n-\varepsilon\}\quad\mbox{ by }(2)\\
&=\mathbb P\{\varepsilon\lt Z_n\}\\
&\leqslant\mathbb P\{ |Z_n|\gt\varepsilon \}  ,
\end{align}
hence by (1), we get the wanted result.